# What is the difference between Node.js require() and RequireJS require()?

Tags: node.js, requirejs

I setup a website with regular client side [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html) today. Than I did some research on node, got that installed and setup my first module in node. When I setup the first require, I loaded the Require.JS file and I get all that. The thing that is confusing me is, I created a file called test.js and within that I am including:

```
var require = require("requirejs");
```

which is actually including the node require, not the original require library I was using right?

So like are they completely different? Can they used together?

Comment: weird. i've never heard of requirejs for node. Seems like it would be pretty much identical. http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html

Comment: Are you asking how to get the two files to communicate or how to use requireJs??

Comment: "Separately, to run my test.js..." should be a separate question on SO ;)

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't Node already have a module loader?

> Yes Node does.
>
> That loader uses the CommonJS module format. The
>   CommonJS module format is non-optimal for the browser, and I do not
>   agree with some of the trade-offs made in the CommonJS module format.
>   By using RequireJS on the server, you can use one format for all your
>   modules, whether they are running server side or in the browser. That
>   way you can preserve the speed benefits and easy debugging you get
>   with RequireJS in the browser, and not have to worry about extra
>   translation costs for moving between two formats. If you want to use
>   define() for your modules but still run them in Node without needing
>   to run RequireJS on the server, see the section below about using
>   amdefine.

Source: http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html#1